# CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: var in this context

Tags: clojure

I use following code to get function name as symbol type

`(:name (meta (var +)))`

However, when I change to this,

`((comp :name meta var) +)`

`CompilerException` is thrown

Answer (score 5):

`var` is one of Clojure's [special forms](http://clojure.org/reference/special_forms). Special forms define a way in which its subexpressions are treated; they may define special syntax and evaluation rules for those subexpressions. Special forms (and `var` operator in particular) are not functions and, in general, cannot be used in the manner functions are used.

Comment: You could write the expression as `((comp :name meta) #'+)` or `(-> + var meta :name)`.